# Unable to load store data in EXTJS Simplestore using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to re-load data into the Store which is further used by a GridPanel. My code goes like:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    myData =     [
        ['document','listsk','123','','','rat'],
        ['hiiiii','himself','rest','','','lap']
    ];

    // create the data store
    store = new Ext.data.SimpleStore({
        fields: [
            {name: 'cat'},
            {name: 'desc'},
            {name: 'edcsId'},
            {name: 'transformedEDCSUrl'},
            {name: 'transformedFormatsUrl'},
            {name: 'lineNotes'}
        ]
    });
    store.loadData(myData);

    // create the Grid
    grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: store,
        columns: [
           {header: "<b>Category</b>",  sortable: true, dataIndex: 'cat'},
           {header: "<b>Description or Document Title</b>", sortable: true,  dataIndex: 'desc'},
           {header: "<b>EDCS ID #</b>", sortable: true, renderer: renderEDCSUrl, dataIndex: 'edcsId'}
           {header: "<b>URLs to Formats</b>", renderer: renderFormatsUrl},
           {id: 'lineNotes', header: "<b>Line Notes</b>", sortable: true, dataIndex: 'lineNotes'}
        ],
        viewConfig: { 
            forceFit: true
        },
        autoExpandColumn: 'lineNotes',
        stripeRows: true,
        collapsible: true
    })

    reload = function refreshGrid(data){
        store.loadData(data);
    }
})
```

The mydata variable as seen by Firebug is:

```
[
    ['document','listsk','123','','','rat'],
    ['hiiiii','himself','rest','','','lap']
]
```

And the data variable in the javascript function refreshGrid is also same:

```
[
    ['document','listsk','123','','','rat'],
    ['hiiiii','himself','rest','','','lap']
]
```

I am invoking the function refreshGrid as follow:

```
function load(response) {  
    reload(response.substring(response.indexOf('myData') + 9, 
           response.indexOf('function renderABC') - 2));
}
```

To me it looks like a JSON parsing issue as data is coming fine from backend. Which is the best way to parse JSON string coming from backend. The behaviour with javascript invcation of `store.loadData` is that each character in the data variable is treated as separate row in the Grid as shown below:

[image: ExtJS Problem]

Comment: Since your question is regarding client-side problems with the store and the grid, I suggest that you remove any server side references (`outBuf.append("...");`) and instead of `rowDataString.toString()` show what the result is. Just to make it easier to understand and answer your question :)

Comment: You haven't shown us how your `grid` is configured. Do you have a `ColumnModel` defined matching your stores `fields` configuration? A far as I know, the grid needs to be explicitly told how to handle the data in the store.

Comment: I have defined columnmodel as show in the edit code above. But still each character is treated as separate row in the javascript string variable "data"

Comment: If I remove the renderers from the ColumnModel, the above code (revision #4) works well for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all who face this problem, a quick wayout is eval function and otherwise use some library for JSON.

Comment: You are allready using such a library. ExtJs has built-in methods Ext.decode and Ext.encode. **Never use eval**.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are providing an array of strings to the store instead of array of arrays as it expects.

As a result, store treats each value of an array(string actually) as an array. As soon as strings support referencing by index(at least in non-IE browsers), you get the behavior described.

Comment: So is there any way by which I can use a String variable to emulate the behavior:       myData =     [
            ['document','listsk','123','','','rat'],
            ['hiiiii','himself','rest','','','lap']
        ];

Comment: No. The solution is to start using arrays of arrays, as intended by ExtJS authors, instead of arrays of strings.

Comment: For the time being I achieved what I wanted to by using eval function in Javascript. Will ask client if he agrees to use some javascript library for converting String to JSON in Javascript.